# Forward user to a specific welcome page with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, authentication

After the user logged-in i would like him to see a page with written "Hello"+his name.
 For redirecting him to the page i'm using this:

```
angular.
 module('myApp').
  config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.
  when('/loginPage',{
       template: '<login-page></login-page >'
     }).
     when('/user-issue', {
       resolve: {
         "check":function($location,$rootScope){
           if(!$rootScope.stat){
             $location.path('/');
           }
         }
       },
       template: '<user-issue></user-issue>'
     }).
     otherwise({redirectTo: '/loginPage'});
}]);
```

How can i pass the value of his name from loginPage.js to userIssue.js page?
I tryed using $rootScope.username in LoginPage to have it in userIssue but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the username as a parameter to the route you're redirecting to through the use of [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).